# Libgdx localisation

Tags: android, file, localization, libgdx

I want create a Localisation file for my project in Libgdx; however, my code is throwing an error.

My code:

```
package com.mygdx.mytest;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.I18NBundle;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MyTest extends ApplicationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void create () {
        FileHandle baseFileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("i18n/MyBundle");
        Locale locale =new Locale("", "", "");
        I18NBundle MyBundle = I18NBundle.createBundle(baseFileHandle, locale);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

My error:

```
I18NBundle MyBundle = I18NBundle.createBundle(baseFileHandle, locale);
```

Where is my mistake? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, but apparently you don't have a bundle.
You need to have a file with path:

```
{project root}/android/assets/i18n/MyBundle.properties
```

Remember to give a error log.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my project and it work fine for me.

```
FileHandle internal = Gdx.files.internal("i18n/lang");
I18NBundle local = I18NBundle.createBundle(internal, Locale.ROOT);
I18NBundle portuguese = I18NBundle.createBundle(internal, new Locale("pt"));
```

Comment: I am having an issue with Hindi localization. My primary language is set to Hindi on my device followed by English and Spanish. So I have added Hindi Localization in my app but it shows second priority language which is english. The strange thing is when I debug the app, it picks up the correct language "hi" but in normal run it doesn't. Please give me some hint/solution.Thanks